# Reading API data - String indices must be integers error

Tags: python, api

I am trying to process api data, but using the code I have to access a dict, I get the "String indices must be integers" error. Any ideas on how to get strings to find the keys in the dict (would prefer not to use integers, and if i do I get the out of range error).

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "1b6ce2494dmshf74f9c461b4cdbbp1d3b11jsndd6ab0d8575c",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
}

url_stats = "https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3/teams/statistics"

qstring_stats1 = {"league":"39","season":"2022","team":"33"}

resp_stats = requests.request("GET", url_stats, headers=headers, params=qstring_stats1)
resp_stats = resp_stats.json()

print(type(resp_stats))
print(resp_stats)

for team in resp_stats["response"]:
    print(str(team["team"]["id"]) + " - " + (team["team"]["name"]))
    print(resp_stats)
```

Output:

```
<class 'dict'>

{'get': 'teams/statistics', 'parameters': {'league': '39', 'season': '2022', 'team': '33'}, 'errors': [], 'results': 11, 'paging': {'current': 1, 'total': 1}, 'response': {'league': {'id': 39, 'name': 'Premier League', 'country': 'England', 'logo': 'https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/39.png', 'flag': 'https://media.api-sports.io/flags/gb.svg', 'season': 2022}, 'team': {'id': 33, 'name': 'Manchester United'}............

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Dropbox\CG\Coding\music_api\main.py", line 47, in <module>
    print(str(team["team"]["id"]) + " - " + (team["team"]["name"]))
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Please do not forget to reset your API key after after receiving a satisfactory response

Comment: What do you mean sorry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong with the last `for` cycle: you loop through keys of the `resp_stats["response"]` dictionary, and they are strings, not dictionaries, thus you cannot get their "team" attribute (`team["team"]`)

According to the structure of `resp_stats["response"]`, there is info on one team only, and you can get it via:

```
team = resp_stats["response"]["team"]
print(str(team["id"]) + " - " + (team["name"]))

>> 33 - Manchester United
```

If this is not the information you need, then you should analyze the structure of the `resp_stats["response"]` dictionary and modify the code in accordance with it.